# Slow internet connection after adding VPN?

Tags: router

Before I had a modem connected to a [wireless N gigabit router](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WRT310N), wired to my PC. That ran fairly fast. Now my brother needs to access his work network, so we've added a [VPN router](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/BEFSX41). The modem is now connected to that, which is connected to the older router, which is wired to my PC. My connection has slowed down a lot and constantly cuts out. Is the new router filtering my connection or what? How can I speed it back up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the router's VPN settings. It's quite possible it's routing *all* of your traffic through his workplace connection.

Comment: That's what I was thinking... I've just disabled the VPN Tunnel now... let's see if that makes things better.

Comment: that likely also disabled your brother's VPN connection to his network, unless the VPN connection is being originated at his laptop.

Answer (score 2):

If your brother merely needs to connect his own PC to his work network, you do not need the VPN router. The VPN router you got is for connecting an entire network to a VPN.

Unless your brother's work has special requirements, all you need to do is set up a VPN connection on his computer (Windows has a built-in VPN Network Connection - or you can use a 3rd party VPN client). This will allow just his computer to be on the VPN while the rest of your network can remain on your ISP.

If you still want to utilize the VPN Router (so that your brother can automatically be on the VPN every time he hooks up to it), connect your Modem > Gigabit Router > VPN Router. That will allow anything connected to the VPN router to be on the VPN while everything on the Gigabit router will remain on your home network.

Comment: And even then: your brother might be required by his employer's policy to route *all* traffic for his computer over that VPN then, for enhanced security. Some details about this Windows' "Use default gateway on remote network" and a Mac's "Send all traffic over VPN connection" at http://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn/29928#29928

Comment: Doing the `Modem > Gigabit Router > VPN Router` thing.. that won't cause any security issues for him? Is there anyway I can set it to only tunnel connections from his PC? Some guy at his work said he needed the VPN router, which is why my bro bought it... so I'm assuming he actually needs it.

Comment: Modem > Router > VPN Router wont' cause security issues. The VPN will still be on its own network. If you want to tunnel just connections from his PC, return the VPN router and just use the gigabit router.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Policy based routing** to have the VPN router selectively encrypt traffic for some IPs and not for others. The simplest solution is to have the VPN router give your brother's computer a static IP address and make that IP address the only address routed thru the VPN.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/732835/34560) for more info.