# Dual Nic - how to VPN from 1, and use inet on 2?

Tags: windows-7, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using a Cisco VPN to get onto my work network. Since my work monitors my internet traffic, I'd like to route it through my 2<sup>nd</sup> NIC, if possible.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: related, possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn

Answer (score 1):

See [2 Internet connections with VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn), especially the note on ["Use default gateway on remote network"](https://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn/29928#29928).

Of course, you will be totally exposing your companies network to whatever malware is connected to the internet without going through the VPN. It's probably much preferred not to mess with this, but instead just limit the time you keep the VPN connected.

Comment: I'm using Cisco VPN, which doesn't have that option. Use default gateway is an option with the built-in Windows VPN client.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the routes appropriately. I'm not sure whether this can be done automatically. Perhaps with permanent entries in the routing table. Take a look at the [route](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx) command. Basically you would set your default route to go through your internet connection, while your work-related subnet should go through the VPN.

Also remember to tell Cisco that it shouldn't disable all other NICs. The default setting is like that.