# How does anonymous VPN work?

Tags: vpn

How do these anonymous VPNs work? They say you can browse the web using a different IP address than your own. How does this work?

I understand the Virtual Private Network model, I am just confused on how I browse the web with a different IP?

Answer (score 2):

Once connected to the VPN (assuming you use an option like "[Use default gateway on remote network](https://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn/29928#29928)" or "Send all traffic over VPN connection"), all your requests are routed through the remote VPN server. So, your IP address for the rest of the world is the IP address of that VPN server (or any server through which the outgoing traffic is routed), not your own IP address.

You connect to that server (yes, using the internet), and that server connects to the rest of the internet. It's just like some web server would not know your local IP address from your own internal network either (like 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x [or similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)).

Comment: So how does my machine know to route its outgoing packets etc using the VPN connection ?

Comment: He, you wrote you understood the VPN model. ;-) Your OS "simply" tells all applications it's part of the other private network, and (assuming the settings I mentioned) not of your local network anymore. (As such, a VPN is totally different from just mapping network drives, or using SSH to access some other network.)

Comment: Cool Cool sounds good , Is there any chance we could chat in more details over gmail of something got a few more questions to ask

Comment: He, you're at a Question & Answer site!

Comment: Cool thanks , If I made a VPN connection to a server then used a PHP Proxy solution to view a page would that be pretty good at being anonymous ?

Comment: That seems to be new question, if not already answered here somewhere. Apart from that I don't really understand what you mean with "a PHP Proxy solution"...

Comment: Even more, now that you apparently started the same question at Stack Overflow (now also at http://superuser.com/questions/68011/anonymous-vpn): please read the FAQs...