# Force a program to connect directly to internet and not using VPN

Tags: vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 Internet connections with VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn)

Hi,

when I am at home and need to connect to work's LAN I use firefox, point to VPN network, so it calls "Network Connect" and then I am like physically at work. And that is the same for every program of Mac OS X, terminal, etc.

Nevertheless, I wonder whether I could tell to some program to connect directly to the internet and not using VPN.

Thanks

Comment: The VPN solutions I've seen in the past always set up the TCP/IP routing table to send only packets destined for the remote network to the remote network, and packets for other addresses are routed 'as normal', before the VPN was set up. Are you sure the route tables have been configured to send all non-local traffic to the VPN end point? That's pretty strange. Check `route -n show` with and without the VPN up to see what's going on.

Comment: See [2 Internet connections with VPN](http://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn) (and note that there a GOOD security reasons to NOT do what you want; see the other question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with Cisco VPN software is that while there was an option that that would allow you to route packets not destined for company resources through your regular DNS, this option was overridden by the VPN server policy so I was out of luck. I'm thinking you're probably going to be in the same boat.