# Allow incoming remote desktop connection when connected to VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop

Environment: Windows 10, Cisco AnyConnect Client

I have a PC at home. I often connect to it when I am out of the home. However, I have to use a VPN client to get in touch of my servers. And the problem is as soon as I connect to the VPN, my home PC can't accept incoming remote desktop connection because of the network environment has changed.

For now, the only workaround I found is that by install Chrome Remote Desktop, I can use Chrome Remote Desktop to connect the home PC when I am not at home and I have to establish a VPN connection on the home PC.

I am wondering if there is a way to make a hole or some DMZ like config so that I can connect to my home PC through the Windows's built-in RDP service when the home PC is connecting to a VPN?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably  a duplicate.

Comment: @G-Man if so, can you link the duplicate or vote close as such?

Comment: [Is it possible to access a remote computer when it is connected a VPN?](https://superuser.com/q/271415/354511)  seems to be nearly the exact same question, but it has only a couple of answers, and they appear not to be very thorough.

Comment: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/q/12022/354511)  seems to be an equivalent question, and it has a dozen answers; the accepted one has over 100 votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not changed the gateway settings for the VPN.

By default, once you make a VPN connection, all network traffic is routed through the VPN. This ensures DNS remains working, but is not necessary.

By disabling use default gateway on remote network, your internal network remains active.

I'm not entirely sure how to change this in the Cisco AnyConnect client though, but I'll write the change for regular VPN, so it might help you find the setting on your Cisco AnyConnect client.

Go to Control Panel -> Network Center -> Adapter settings -> VPN Connection

Right click the connection and choose Properties.

Access the tab Networking
Doubleclick the TCP-IP v4

Press <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

Uncheck `Use default gateway on remote network`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the configuration of Cisco AnyConnect, it is different with a regular VPN. There are limited setting options in AnyConnect's adapter. But I found there is an "Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN (if configured)" option in AnyConnect Client App. If I enable it, the route to my local network (192.168.100.0/24) won't be routed to VPN. I guess this is all I can get for now. I am trying to do some further configuration about my router, but still no luck for now.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly the setting I was referring to.