# Cisco AnyConnect VPN only in running terminal session on OsX Sierra

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, terminal, cisco-vpn-client

I want to keep my work/personal network separated on my machine.

I want a script that after running that the current terminal session connects to my work network using Cisco AnyConnect (handles username/pass/host/accept certificate). But I want only the session that is running the script to use the VPN after that.

I have seen [How to selectively route network traffic through VPN on Mac OS X Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard) and [How to force split tunnel routing on Mac to a Cisco VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/91191/how-to-force-split-tunnel-routing-on-mac-to-a-cisco-vpn?newreg=8d8e4a685f834949a20fd5fe633ddc1f) and other links but I really don't know if they are answering my question and a bit too complicated for me.

Comment: If your VPN administrator has configured to Tunnel All traffic, then there isn't much you can do. Administrator can push split-include rules to the AnyConnect client which helps to tunnel office related network traffic only through VPN.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it possible to access a remote computer when it is connected to a VPN?](https://superuser.com/q/271415/354511)

Comment: Possibly useful as a reference: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/q/12022/354511) While it is specifically addressed to Windows, there is some general information on techniques and tools.