# Data through VPN vs Internet?

Tags: vpn, internet, internet-connection

I connect to client VPN through internet. I have two questions on how data flows through VPN vs data flow through the Internet. Here they are:

1. I believe the difference b/w transferring the data either through VPN or internet is data is secured in VPN. In case of VPN too, data still travels through internet i.e. `My computer > MyISP >Internet Exchange > Client ISP > Client Network` but data is encrypted  which can be unlocked by client only. Correct?
2. If the above is correct and data is transferred through internet even on VPN , Why i am not able access the internet on VPN once connection is established with client network?

Comment: make english clear. i dont understand what you are saying

Comment: See now. I added more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-VPN traffic could be simplified to show as:

> Browser > OS > internet > web server

Above, the browser asks your computer's operating system (OS) for a connection to the internet, which most likely first goes through some modem/router in your own network, and your ISP's servers.

When using a public VPN (like to securely use untrusted public WiFi networks, or to fool a web server you're in a different country), the flow is like:

> Browser > OS > **encrypt** > internet > VPN provider > **decrypt** > internet > web server

So, the browser does not even know it's using a VPN (the operating system takes care of that) and the VPN provider decrypts the VPN traffic and then forwards it to the target server.

When visiting a HTTPS website, the traffic is encrypted by the browser and web server as well. Without VPN:

> Browser > **encrypt** > OS > internet > web server > **decrypt**

When using both HTTPS and VPN the traffic is encrypted twice. In that case the VPN provider can only decrypt the VPN traffic but cannot see what the browser is actually transmitting:

> Browser > **encrypt** > OS > *encrypt* > internet > VPN provider > *decrypt* > internet > web server > **decrypt**

Note that if it's a private VPN (like to connect to a company's network) then the VPN server might also allow traffic to the internet:

> Browser > OS > encrypt > internet > company VPN > decrypt > **company network** > internet > web server

However, private VPNs are often configured to not route traffic to any external website:

> Browser > OS > encrypt > internet > company VPN > decrypt > **company network only**

To get around that, the VPN client on your computer's OS might allow for using VPN only for *some* of the traffic. Like on a Windows computer, by disabling options [such as](https://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn/29928#29928) "Use default gateway on remote network" the OS will only use the VPN for traffic to your company's network, but for other traffic just connect to the internet as usual. That might be a security risk though (like malware on your computer can connect to both the company network and any other server on the internet at the same time!) and should not be changed unless you truly understand the risks.

Comment: when you say `For that, the OS might allow for using VPN ...` i believe you are refering to VPN server OS ?

Comment: @user3198603, when using Windows on your computer, the Windows OS (operating system) has some option _"Use default gateway on remote network"_ in its VPN settings. On a Mac, this may be called something like _"Send all traffic over VPN connection"_. (See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/29922/2-internet-connections-with-vpn/29928#29928).) Or when using specific VPN software on your computer, that software might have some settings for that too.

Comment: Ok i believe you mean if  set "Use default gateway on remote network"  on vpn client machine OS, i will be able to access internet(other site) alongwith VPN network but they can be security threat for sensitive data which is meant for client only ?

Comment: @user3198603, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am not sure if you typed it right .`Like on a Windows computer, by disabling options such as "Use default gateway on remote network" one could only use the VPN for traffic to your company's network, but not for other traffic.` After going this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/317025, i believe if i disable this option i can access other website traffic alongwith client network. Is n't it ?

Comment: Edited again...

Answer (score 1):

VPN stands for Virtual Private Network. It enables you to access your private network securely from the public network (The Internet).

VPN works very similar to what you described except the last part is usually called "VPN server" as opposed to "client"

To access a website:

Without VPN:

`User -> ISP1 -> Internet -> ISP3 -> Website`

With VPN:

`User (Through VPN client) -> ISP1 -> Internet -> ISP2 -> (VPN Server) -> ISP2 -> Internet -> ISP3 -> Website`

The VPN Encryption is only between the User and the VPN server.
Data travelling after the VPN server is as secure as the website you are contacting.

**So yes**, data between User and VPN server can only be decrypted by one of them.

If your setup is this:

`User (Through VPN client) -> ISP1 -> Internet -> ISP2 -> (VPN Server)`

It's called site-to-site connection. (Example: Company branch to head office).

Depending of the VPN server configurations and routing tables. You can do exactly as in the example above and enable access to the Internet.

In fact, this is exactly how VPN providers work.

Example:

`User in China -> ISP (CN) -> Internet -> ISP (DE) -> VPN Server in Germany -> ISP (DE) -> Internet -> ISP (US) -> Facebook`

Your ability to access the internet would depend on your VPN Server network configuration.

Comment: `The VPN Encryption is only between the User and the VPN server. Data travelling after the VPN server is as secure as the website you are contacting.` i did not get the use of of encryption here as my machine(vpn to client) data travels in encrypted form but from vpn server to client server data travel in decrypted for, Why encryption is relaxed from vpn server to client network ? Is it not security risk ?

Comment: It's not VPN to Client. It's Client to Server. You are the client and you connect to the VPN server.
This whole communication back and forth is encrypted.
If you are accessing the internet from the VPN server, that connection is not encrypted after the VPN server. Of course when you get the data back it will be encrypted and sent to you.

Comment: looks like i was not clear in my last comment. My question is why data is only encrypted from vpn client(which is mine machine) to vpn server. Why data from vpn server to client network is not encrypted. Is it not security threat ?

Comment: `Client -> ... -> VPN Server` is all Encrypted in **BOTH** directions.
If you are using VPN to bypass content blocking and requesting a site through the VPN Server then:
`VPN Server -> ... -> Website` is not Encrypted by VPN encryption because your tunnel is over (Only between Client and server).

Comment: `VPN Server -> ... -> Website is not Encrypted by VPN encryption because your tunnel is over (Only between Client and server)` is it not security threat ? My point is if we don't see security threat here then why do we need encryption even between `Client -> ... -> VPN Server` ?

Comment: The first line of my original answer described the main purpose for VPN. Instead of exposing all unencrypted services in your network to the Internet, you use VPN.
The other use for common users is to connect through another server in a different country securely so your connection cannot be snooped on or blocked by government for example. Some use proxies, but they are usually not encrypted.
As for "Is it a security threat?"
1. You cannot do anything about it, you rely on the website to do it. VPN's role is over here.
2. Most websites encrypt these days. [link](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the Client VPN (your connection to your VPN server) can be configured.

Full Tunnel

Split Tunnel

In a Full Tunnel, when you connect to the VPN Server, it tells your client that *all* traffic is to be encrypted, and by default, routed across the VPN to the VPN Server.

At that point, your VPN Server can deny passing any traffic from you, out of *its* network connection to the internet.

In a Split Tunnel, the VPN Server gives only a subset of network routes to your client.  Your client then looks at its local routing table to see if the traffic it is going to send, is going to go out to the internet without your VPN, or if it will go into the VPN.

Split Tunnel vpn's are less secure, but faster for non-encrypted traffic.

Lets say you want to connect to your server across the VPN .. you want to RDP to 192.168.15.101 .. but in your haste you accidentally type 102.168.15.101 ... Your VPN client would look at the routes it was given .. see that 102.168.15.101 is not in 192.168.15.x and route the traffic directly out of your NIC to the internet.  If someone is running a sniffer, or a honey pot your accidental 102.168 ... could expose your user name, your computer name, and the password.

Split Tunnel configurations can be faster for you, the client, for two reasons.  Encrypting traffic is CPU intensive, so the less you are encrypting, the more your CPU could spend on just moving traffic.

And second, if all traffic goes into the VPN .. it has to go from where you are, to the VPN serer, and *then* go out to the internet.

Think of wanting to go to the store .. the fastest way is in a straight line to that store from where you are.  Putting everything into a VPN .. instead of going straight to the store .. you first detour to the post office 5 miles in the opposite direction, and then drive to that same store.